# What is the speed difference between downloading with URL and Sockets?

Tags: java, performance, sockets

I'm looking to create a Java application which will download podcasts to someone's computer automatically. I'm wondering whether I should be making a Socket connection to my server or simply using the URL class.

Does anyone know what the speed difference is between downloading through a URL vs a socket connection. I know the URL object is built in part on top of the Socket object, but I'm not sure what the difference in run time is.

Comment: I would say, generally, it's insignificant that in most cases it would irrelevant.  Generally, you would need implement the protocol overhead that URL implements for you any way, so at the end of the day, you'd be doing the same thing.

Comment: Why should there be any difference? Would your socket transfer a different kind of data?

Comment: The difference between your program speed and the networks speed is sooooo different.

Comment: @MadProgrammer so unless I'm connecting to server for which I write my own protocol it's negligibly slower to use URL?

Comment: @NickChapman Without going through actually testing it, I would think so.

Comment: @NickChapman I would also imagine that `URL` has being optimised for "general" use, so in some specialized cases, where you control the hardware and software involved, you may be able to get better performance by rolling your own solution, but remember, `URL` was designed to interact with certain protocols..

Comment: You might also consider the [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/); I would expect that they all are bound by network speed, so pick whichever has an API you prefer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the existing library support. The only reason to use a Socket directly for this task is when connecting to a *custom* protocol (i.e. *not* HTTP for which there is no suitable implementation). There are so many existing transfer protocols - don't waste time creating another for this generic case.

HttpURLConnection is ultimately implemented with TCP Sockets that "speak" HTTP. Using Sockets directly would require writing the code to understand HTTP - in whatever context is required. This code, even if done "more efficiently" than HttpUrlConnection will represent only a *small fraction* of the actual execution time which will be dominated by other factors.

Instead, consider how speed can be improved at a higher-level:

- Download multiple remote resources concurrently
- Using HTTP pipelining, where applicable
- Enable HTTP compression, when applicable
- Switch to a different protocol designed for multi-file synchronization